# Determine order of set iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, set

I have two iterators (say `it1` and `it2`) into the same `std::set<int>`. They are obtained through `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`, therefore they are not safe to dereference (they could equal `end()`).
Is there an easy and safe way of telling which one goes first?

I could call `std::distance(it1, it2)` and `std::distance(it2, it1)`, but that does not seem to help since if `it1 != it2` then one of the calls is UB. I could test `*it1 < *it2`, but only if no iterator points to the `end()`. Finally, I could first test for the end iterator and then do the above comparison on values.

Is there an elegant solution based purely on iterators and not involving the values, i.e., dereferencing? I am willing to use up to c++14 and maybe boost.

**EDIT** (in reponse to comments):
I use a set because I want fast lookup and insertion, in particular much faster than linear complexity. A sorted vector would be a possible alternative, it would trivially solve the problem, but insertion and removal are linear time operations.

Comment: The iterators returned by `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` will always define a valid range: `[lower, upper)`. You don't need to check it. If the two are equal the range is empty, just like any other range.

Comment: unless you mean you have something akin to `auto [it1, it2] = set.equal_range(value); if (rand()%2) swap(it1, it2);`

Comment: The iterators don't come from lower and upper bound on the same value, and the logic is somewhat involved, so the iterators could be in any order. Though, I could of course keep track of the values passed to the bound functions...

Comment: "Is there an elegant solution" yes change logic so iterators always come in order

Comment: Obvious solution is to use sorted vector instead of `std::set<>` but there is no enough details to say if such solution is feasable

Comment: Thanks for the sorted vector suggestion. I use the set for its reasonable trade-off between insert/delete and lookup complexity. In my case I may indeed be able to work with a sorted vector since there are more lookups than modifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way is to fix your code logic and have `[it1,it2)` always be a valid range; if this turns out not possible (but how can it be ?), you may use something like

```
// O(N), forward iterators, it1, it2 should belong to range
template<class Iter>
bool precedes_or_is_equal( Iter it1, Iter it2, Iter end )
{
  while( it1 != end && it1 != it2 ) ++it1;

  return it1 == it2;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution but it is more expensive than dereferencing

Comment: @Slava you're totally right, but you'd need to match the value type operator to the given set<> comparator ... ymmv; as said, the best way is to simply  fix the code the op didn't show

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I use the set in the first place to avoid linear complexity. Sorry for not showing the full code, but it seems to me that the question is of interest in its own right. Since the set is a tree, it should be possible to solve the problem in logarithmic time, but apparently this is not possible with the interfaces provided by the standard.

Comment: @tglas the problem is that, as per question requirements, we cannot dereference the iterators; otherwise, a constant-time solution would be possible by simply using the "set<>" comparator directly ...

Comment: @Massimiliano: The only iterators that cannot be dereferenced are end iterators, all others can. So testing for end() first and then dereferencing works. But since the set is a (rb or avl) tree under the hood, the problem should (in a perfect world) be solvable in logarithmic time using only the iterators.

Comment: @tglas I know we can dereference them :), I was referring to *your* question requirements ("Is there [...] based **purely on iterators and not involving the values**?)" that said, I agree with you, in theory we could have an iterator category with the property that they can be compared in log time; but, they would dereference their values under the hood anyway, so who cares ?